# How store a JSON array with ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, servicestack

I know how stored a simple JSON message in a table, but How can I store easily my data in this same table if I generate a JSON array?
ex:

> [{"ID":0,"Data1":123,"Data2":"String1","Timestamp":"/Date(-62135596800000-0000)/"},{"ID":0,"Data1":456,"Data2":"String2","Timestamp":"/Date(-62135596800000-0000)/"}]

I tried something like this but <del>it doesn't work</del> it doesn't compile:

```
public class Table1
{
    public List<Table1> Table1LIST{ get; set; }

    [AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public int Data1{ get; set; }
    public string Data2{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

// Add Table1 via POST
[Route("/Table1ADD", Verbs = "POST")]
public class Table1 ADD
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public int Data1{ get; set; }
    public string Data2{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

// Add multi Table1 via POST
[Route("/Table1ADDMulti", Verbs = "POST")]
public class Table1 ADDMulti
{
    public List<Table1 > Table1LIST { get; set; }
}

    // Store JSON array
    public object Post(Table1Multi request)
    {
        var data =new Table1()
        {
            Table1LIST = request.Table1LIST
        };

        CRUDFunctions CRUD = new CRUDFunctions(Db);
        return CRUD.AddData(data);
    }
```

I use the function insert to store my data (CRUD.AddData()). This function specify that it is possible to store several rows in the same time.

The idea is to avoid to send multiple message.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did my suggestion help?

Comment: Yes thanks, I am working on it, It's just when I'm trying to post an array I don't get anything in "request" in debug mode. Are you sure it's a List<int> I should use to store multiple Table1, Shouldn't be List<Table1> instead?

Comment: The `List<int>` is the return type, i.e. you can return a list of the Insert Ids. I'll update my answer to make this more clear, give me 20 minutes.

Comment: I have updated the answer to resolve your issue of the DTO not being populated. Please let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close, except you shouldn't be adding a `List<Table1>` to `Table1`. Instead create `Table1` as below, and make a simple DTO such as `Table1Multiple` to handle multiple values.

```cs
[Route("/Table1","POST")]
public class Table1 : IReturn<int>
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public int Data1 { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

[Route("/Table1/Multi","POST")]
public class Table1Multiple : IReturn<List<int>>
{
    public List<Table1> Values { get; set; }
}
```

In the service you should reuse the code used to store a single record, and simply iterate the list of `Table1` `Values`.

```cs
class TestService : Service
{
    // Stores a single Table1 record
    public int Post(Table1 request)
    {
        // Add your method to store a single record
        var CRUD = new CRUDFunctions(Db);
        return CRUD.AddData(request); // Return the ID of the created record
    }

    // Stores multiple Table1 records
    public List<int> Post(Table1Multiple request)
    {
        // Return a list of the record Ids
        var result = new List<int>();

        // Process each request, through the single record code
        foreach(var value in request.Values)
            result.Add(Post(value));

        return result;
    }
}
```

---

#### Addressing your non-populated DTO

`I don't get anything in "request" in debug mode.`

You have two choices. You can change the request to use a property `values`

```
{values:[{"ID":0,"Data1":123,"Data2":"String1","Timestamp":"/Date(-62135596800000-0000)/"},
         {"ID":0,"Data1":456,"Data2":"String2","Timestamp":"/Date(-62135596800000-0000)/"}]}
```

**Or** you can change the request DTO to extend from the `List<Table1>` instead:

```cs
// 
[Route("/Table1/Multi","POST")]
public class Table1Multiple : List<Table1>, IReturn<List<int>>
{
}
```

Then modify the service so it reads `var value in request` instead of `var value in request.Values`

```cs
class TestService : Service
{
    // Stores a single Table1 record
    public int Post(Table1 request)
    {
        // Add your method to store a single record
        var CRUD = new CRUDFunctions(Db);
        return CRUD.AddData(request); // Return the ID of the created record
    }

    // Stores multiple Table1 records
    public List<int> Post(Table1Multiple request)
    {
        // Return a list of the record Ids
        var result = new List<int>();

        // Process each request, through the single record code
        foreach(var value in request) // Collection changed here
            result.Add(Post(value));

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still doesn't work, I get an error "(405) Method Not Allowed"

Comment: I don't know what method your have tried. It's a little hard to debug your program without seeing it. If you could link to the source code, say on GitHub, it may be possible to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I never used Github but I will. I give you the limk when it's done, thanks for your help

Comment: I have created a complete example of what you where trying to do [here](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/f021d7f81be849e5306a). You should consider using a consistent naming convention in future, and try and keep your code neat and concise - it will make it easier to understand and debug errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scott for you help and advise. I learned everything by myself, so I have some problem to organised and make my code neat. Your structure makes thinks clear, I will keep it in mind. Thanks again